# Clip path Polygon

Tags: html, css, button, clip-path

my css code is :

```
.myButton {
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px -50px #91b8b3;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:4px solid #566963;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color: yellow;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:12px 23px;
    text-decoration:none;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

I am expecting the text should be yellow and background should be transparent and border should be 4px yellow, and need borders on all sides, and shape will be the same as given button[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPPf7.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can rely on pseudo-element and generate a specific `clip-path` for the border. I have a generator for this: https://css-generators.com/custom-corners/

[image: CSS Generators: Custom Corners]

```css
button {
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  position: relative;
}

button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: -5px;
  background: #91b8b3;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0,calc(100% - 1.00em) 0,100% 1.00em,100% calc(100% - 1.00em),calc(100% - 1.00em) 100%,0 100%,0 0,5px  5px ,5px calc(100% - 5px),calc(100% - 1.00em - 2.07px) calc(100% - 5px),calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 1.00em - 2.07px),calc(100% - 5px) calc(1.00em + 2.07px),calc(100% - 1.00em - 2.07px) 5px,5px 5px);
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```

Comment: Can i use hover effect for borders or background?